# Check directory's sharing mode in windows

Tags: c++, windows

My question is seems to be simple, but google is silent. I'm banned may be?:)

So the question is can I check is there any blocked from deleting file in directory or it's subdirectories before delete it? Is there simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

And even if there was, it wouldn't work. Consider this sequence of events:

1. You perform the check and it succeeds (there is no blocked files).
2. Another process receives CPU quantum and opens a file without FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag.
3. Your process gains the CPU back and proceeds to delete the directory -- only to discover that it can't, because now there **is** a blocked file.

Comment: ok, but here is my way (I really need it):
I just recursively try to get handles of all files and subdirectories in the directory with FILE_SHARE_READ or 0, storing them into array. And if I got all handles, I can now delete files.
Not as easy as I want, but possible:)

Comment: @fadim - This does not preclude some process from creating a new file which your enumeration will miss. There is no way to make it bulletproof. It means that you still have to handle correctly the situation when the deletion fails midway. And once you have that, why spend extra effort on preliminary check?